# Calculate overall balance with records including various add and sub operations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame `df` with columns `type`, `timestamp`, `value` and `team`. The type can be `add` (adding value) or `sub` (subtracting value). The records log the payments given or taken away for a particular team. I would like to calculate the overall balance of how much I spent for all teams overall and how much per team. Note, that I could pay `X` to particular team `A` on eg Monday, then on Tuesday get back `X`, and then pay team `A` amount `Y` on Friday. Is there some nice panda way to do that? Here is an example of how the data looks:

| Type | Timestamp | Value | Team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| add | 1675971432 | 20 | A |
| add | 1675971392 | 50 | C |
| sub | 1675877813 | 15 | A |
| add | 1675877579 | 10 | D |
| add | 1675877528 | 20 | B |
| add | 1675877128 | 15 | A |

Comment: what do you expect from that data?

Comment: @QuangHoang As mentioned in my post, I would like to calculate the overall balance of how much I spent for all teams overall and how much per team.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from you is that you want two new columns:

First columns is to reflect the overall net balance (sum of (add) - sum of (sub))
and the second column is to reflect the net balance per team

In order to achieve the goal you need a dummy column which you may delete subsequently.

#### To create the first dummy column:

```
import numpy as np

df['dummy'] = np.where(df.Type=='add',df.Value, df.Value *-1)
```

#### now you will create the first column "overall"

```
df['overall'] = sum(df.dummy)
```

#### The second column

```
df['netbalance']= df.groupby('Team')['dummy'].transform('sum')
```

#### finally you will delete the dummy column

```
df.drop(columns='dummy',inplace=True)
```

Comment: np.where function works exactly like MS-Excel's if formula. You can also use nested condition under np.where, but in the above case it is not required.

Comment: In case you dont' want to create the columns for overall spend or net spend you can get the result by summing by:
sum(df.dummy)    # to get the overall


df.groupby('Team')['dummy'].sum()  # to see the net spend for each team